# In Java, a "decorate and sort" concise implementation?

Tags: java, comparator

I'm learning Java for the first time (my prior experience is Python and Haskell). I have a situation that would, in Python, require a "decorate and sort" idiom. Such as the following (code not tested but this is roughly correct):

```
origList = <something>
decorated = sorted( [(evalFunc(item), item) for item in origList] )
finalList = [item for _, item in decorated]
```

By choosing a different `evalFunc` you can choose how this is sorted.

In Java, I'm writing a program that composes music by choosing from among a list of notes, evaluating the "fitness" of each note, and picking the best. I have a class representing musical notes:

```
class Note {
   ...
}
```

I have a class that represents the fitness of a note as two values, its goodness and badness (yes, these are separate concepts in my program). Note: in Python or Haskell, this would simply be a 2-tuple, but my understanding is that Java doesn't have tuples in the usual sense. I could make it a pair, but it gets unwieldy to declare variables all over the place like `List<Pair<Type1,Pair<Type2,Type3>>>`. (As an aside, I don't think Java has type aliases either, which would let me shorten the declarations.)

```
class Fitness {
    double goodness;
    double badness;
}
```

The function that evaluates the fitness needs access to several pieces of data other than the Note. We'll say it's part of a "Composition" class:

```
class Composition {
    ... data declared here ... ;

    public Fitness evaluate(Note n) {
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to compare `Fitness` objects in numerical order. There are two ways to compare: either goodness or badness can be numerically compared, depending on the situation.

```
class CompareFitnessByGoodness implements Comparator<Fitness> {
}

class CompareFitnessByBadness implements Comparator<Fitness> {
}
```

I'd like to package the `Note` together with its fitness, so I can sort the combined list by fitness and later pull out the best `Note`.

```
class Together {
    public Note;
    public Fitness;
}
```

I'd like to sort a `List<Together>` by either the goodness, or by the badness. So I might need:

```
class CompareTogetherByGoodness implements Comparator<Together> {
    ...
}

class CompareTogetherByBadness implements Comparator<Together> {
   ...
}
```

Eventually I'll write something like

```
Note pickBest(List<Together> notes) {
    // Pick a note that's not too bad, and pretty good at the same 
    // time.

    // First sort in order of increasing badness, so I can choose
    // the bottom half for the next stage (i.e. the half "least bad"
    // notes).
    Collections.sort(notes, new CompareTogetherByBadness());
    List<Together> leastBadHalf = notes.subList(0, notes.size()/2);

    // Now sort `leastBadHalf` and take the last note: the one with
    // highest goodness.
    Collections.sort(leastBadHalf, new CompareTogetherByGoodness());

    return leastBadHalf.get(leastBadHalf.size()-1);
}
```

Whew! That is a LOT of code for something that would be a few lines in Haskell or Python. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

Addressing some of the answers.

"You don't need to decorate." Well, my fitness computation is very expensive, so I want to compute it once for each note, and save the result for later access as well.

"Store goodness/badness in Note." The goodness or badness is not a property of the note alone; it's only meaningful in context and it can change. So this is a suggestion that I add mutable state which is only meaningful in some contexts, or plain wrong if there's a bug which accidentally mutates it. That's ugly, but maybe a necessary crutch for Java.

Comment: Yes, use Haskell or Python.

Comment: **Don't** make everything public, and you can do better - but something like `Collections.sort(notes, (a, b) -> Double.valueOf(a.fitness.badness).compareTo(b.fitness.badness));` ? See also [`Comparator.comparingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-)

Comment: Whie at it, In Python you don't need to decorate the sequence at all, you can just do `sorted(origList, key=evalFunc)`.

Comment: Why not just `Collections.sort(notes, new CompareTogetherByGoodness());` and take the last one?

Comment: @smac89 or even Collections.max(notes, new CompareTogetherByGoodness());

Comment: @smac89 : read the post more carefully; "goodness" and "badness" are independent concepts. A Note could have high goodness and high badness, low of both, or high of one and low of the other.  I'm not finding the "best" note: I'm finding the note with highest goodness among the half of the notes with least badness.

Comment: @SeanBright, thanks for the laugh. :) However, I'm training myself in Java in order to tutor it to college kids, and I need to know best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by what you already have

```
origList = <something>
decorated = sorted( [(evalFunc(item), item) for item in origList] )
finalList = [item for _, item in decorated]
```

This is the equivalent in modern Java:

Given your composition object:

```
Composition composer = ...;
```

And a list of notes:

```
List<Note> notes = ...;
```

Then you can do:

```
List<Together> notesAllTogetherNow = notes.stream()
                                          .map(note -> new Together(note, composer.evaluate(note)))
                                          .sorted(new CompareTogetherByGoodness())
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To get the best note, you can take a bit further:

```
Optional<Note> bestNote = notes.stream()
                               .map(note -> new Together(note, composer.evaluate(note)))
                               .sorted(new CompareTogetherByBadness())
                               .limit(notes.size() / 2) // Taking the top half
                               .sorted(new CompareTogetherByGoodness())
                               .findFirst() // Assuming the last comparator sorts in descending order
                               .map(Together::getNote);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use streams:

```
Function<Foo, Bar> func = ...
Comparator<Foo> comparator = ...
var list = ...
var sorted = list.stream()
                 .sorted(comparator)
                 .map(func)  
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You don't need the `func` and `.map(func)` as long as the comparator does its job. The idea of decoration / undecoration is to return the _same_ data type sorted in a custom way.

Comment: This is a fine answer, but I think it misses the point. You could change the implementation of `pickBest`, but OP appears to be bemoaning the requisite amount of boilerplate code that is required in Java.

Comment: by using a stream you're forced to create a new list which can be avoided with `list.sort(comparator);`.

Answer (score 1):

Java plainly includes a [`Collections.sort :: List -> Comparator -> List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) that does everything for you. It mutates the original list, though.

Unfortunately, Java's standard library does not include tuples and even a plain `Pair`; the Apache Commnons library does, though.

In short, you *don't need* the decorate / undecorate approach in Java.

Comment: See my edits; my fitness function is **extraordinarily** expensive, so I only want to compute it once.

Comment: Oops, should also mention I need to save it for later examination, so between that and the fact I only want to compute it once, means I think decorating is best. What do you think?

Comment: Collections.sort does *not* cache the result of the compare, which means it does *not* decorate.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Fitness {
    double goodness;
    double badness;
}

class Together {
    Note note;
    Fitness fitness;
}

class Note{
}

    List<Together> notes = ...
    Collections.sort(notes, Comparator.comparingDouble(value -> value.fitness.badness));
    List<Together> leastBadHalf = notes.subList(0, notes.size()/2);
    return leastBadHalf.stream().max(Comparator.comparingDouble(value -> value.fitness.goodness));
```